# Robot localization without any sensors

Tags: localization, mapping

Is it possible to localize a robot without any sensors, odometer and servo motors?

Assume robot has dc motors and no obstacles.

Comment: Its quite vague description of what you need. You can locate any object with triangulation. Object needs to have a way to detect at least three indoor beacons. Accuracy depends on technology used. If you need to track the robot position, it is hard to do without any sensors. With aceelerometer you could calculate the directional vector and probably determine location..

Comment: Can you give more information localization using three indoor beacons? Any article or tutorial will be helpful.

Comment: @ronroo Can you give more details of your application? As stated your question is very vague and would be hard to help other users. By definition you would need at least one sensor to get any feedback, even a beacon is technically a sensor.

Comment: @aerophilic you are right! But I will create a new topic for my application which uses sensors and cameras. But for this topic I was trying to explore solution without any sensor.

Comment: I have created a new topic here, any explaination will be helpful. http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/robot-localization-using-three-beacons

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know the wheel radius and the speed of the robot, you will be able to calculate its location at any time relatively to its initial position.

```
travelled_distance = Speed * time;
current_position = initial_position + travelled_distance;
```

This is a simplified 1-dimensional equation than can help you. But keep in mind that without sensors and odometry the localization can't be very accurate.

Comment: This is typically called dead-reckoning.

Comment: Hi thanks for this, any solution for turning? Without sensor I think it will not be accurate.

Comment: Turning depends on the motion model of your robot, is it differential ?