# Path planning of wheeled robot

Tags: mobile-robot, robotic-arm, wheeled-robot, motion-planning, path-planning

let's say the robot Looks like this (an usual robot arm with 4 wheels) :

[image]

In this case as far as I know, the idea of path planning is just to compare the actual position x with the desired position x_goal. At the end, the robot would be at the position x_goal.

[image]

But the Question is how to set this x_goal. If the robot doesnt have an arm, then x_goal is equal to the position that the robot has to be there. But since the robot has an arm, x_goal must takes account the reachability and singularity of the arm.

What would be the most common/efficient way to estimate this x_goal in this case?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Joe. I think this question is a duplicate of another question [I answered in quite a lot of detail](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/16448/9720) previously, so I'm going to mark this question as a duplicate and close it. **If the answer there doesn't answer your question**, please *edit your question* to explain what is still giving you trouble and we can reopen this question and try to address those problems.

Comment: The brief overview of the answer there is that you need to modify your $x_{goal}$ position to get the arm (it was a beacon in the other question) to the target position. There are several graphics at the other answer that hopefully make everything clear.

Answer (score 0):

Pathplanning for a wheeled robot consists of transferring domain specific knowledge into the software. Requirements like determine the xgoal position and take care of reachability of the robotarm are usually not given as a machine readable description but as expert knowledge of how to manual control the robot with a joystick. What the system engineer has to do is to convert weak defined knowledge into a pathplanner which gets executed autonomously. One option in doing so is a fuzzy control system. In contrast to the famous myth, these systems can be used in complex domains, for example pathplanning.

> Quote: “This paper treats the autonomous navigation problem of robotic
>   systems in a dynamic and uncertain environment. [...] The fuzzy logic
>   is certainly one of the most adopted approaches in industry.“
>
> Boufera, Fatma, et al. "Fuzzy control system for autonomous navigation
>   of thymio II mobile robots." Journal of Emerging Technologies in Web
>   Intelligence 6.1 (2014): 101-105.

Before the pathplanner can be realized with fuzzy-rules and linguistic variables, the requirements have to be written down in natural language. This is part of the software engineering process and is done in expert-interviews. That are humans, how have controlled the robot platform in the past with a joystick and are able to explain which details are important for reaching a position.